# CSV read and write loop-MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv

My question is (I assume) simple, but have been unable to crack it after many days on the search. I was thus hoping that some of you might be able to help me. If indeed you can, please let me know, it is very important to me. My problem is the following:

I am working on a project in MATLAB. After running some simulations, I end up with 100 csv files, named Run1_Mon_m2, Run2_Mon_m2,.......,Run100_Mon_m2. The files consist of 10 columns and 289 rows, headers for each included. What I want to do is the following:

From each of the 100 csv files, I need to pick the 3rd column and import it to a new csv file, let's call it Final. In the end, Final will consist of 100 columns and 289 rows, headers included, made from the 3rd columns of my original 100 files.

It would be ideal if that could be achieved through MATLAB. If you have absolutely no idea how to do so, then any other method is greatly appreciated as well. If any of you fellow programmers out there could assist me, I would literally be in your debt. Many thanks for any and all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each file with `readtable` and then extract the column that you want using the indexing functions on the table, e.g. `t = readtable('Run1_Mon_m2.csv');` to get the table into `t` and then `t(:,3)` to get the third column.  Start with the documents here and read on the table type:

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html

Comment: When I tried to run the loop for 100 times, after the 1st time I get an error (while using writetable) that I have duplicate variable name, which is to be expected since the columns i extract present the same data. How do I overcome this??

Comment: You need to concatenate the tables in the program before you write them to disk, I would think.  Your description of the problem is pretty vague though, so it's hard to be sure what exactly you're doing.  Really you should post a minimal working example to be on-topic for this site.